# Bitly API call using VBA Excel Macro

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, bitly

I'm trying to make an Excel Macro to automatically shorten URLs in an Excel file.

[image] ().

I found existing code however this applies to an old version of the API:
[image]

Bitly has instructions on how to connect to the new API version, however these are not written in VBA:
[image]

The Bitly API instructions also contain instructions on how to convert a V3 API call to a V4 API call:
[image]

I tried to fix this. In Excel I get the error

> '{"message":"FORBIDDEN"'

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim Json, URL, result, AccToken, LongURL As String
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B6:B100")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'If users selects more than one cell, exit sub to prevent bugs
    If Target.Value = Empty Then Exit Sub
    AccToken = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
    If AccToken = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your Bitly Access Token to get started" & vbCrLf & "hoi"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    LongURL = Target.Value

    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"

    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, LongURL, False

    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer {" & AccToken & "}"
    'objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer {TOKEN}"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"

    objHTTP.send (Json)
    result = objHTTP.responseText
    Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

    Set objHTTP = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to remove the brackets in your authorization: `objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & AccToken` the token should be without `{ }`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that helped! It  solved 1 issue, however I get another error message now:. I suppose my request is incorrect? {"message":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","resource":"bitlinks","description":"The JSON value provided is invalid."

Comment: Well the issue is you `Dim Json` but you set no value to this variable (it is empty) and so you send and empty request `objHTTP.send (Json)`. • Additionally note that if you declare `Dim Json, URL, result, AccToken, LongURL As String` only `LongURL` will be of type `String` but all others of type `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim Json As String, URL As String, result As String, AccToken As String, LongURL As String` or they are `Variant` by default.

Comment: Also your `objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, LongURL, False` should be `objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False` and the `LongURL` probably needs to go into the `JSON` somehow, Like send teh parameters in `-d` of your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCohj.png as JSON encoded parameters with `objHTTP.send (Json)`. • Since you posted it as an image I cannot copy it to write an answer (see [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I'm so sorry: `curl \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X POST \
-d '{
  "long_url": "https://dev.bitly.com",
  "domain": "bit.ly",
  "group_guid": "Ba1bc23dE4F"
}' \
https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten`

Comment: Set your `Json` variable like `Json = "{""long_url"": ""https://dev.bitly.com"",   ""domain"": ""bit.ly"",   ""group_guid"": ""Ba1bc23dE4F""}"`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are the best, it's working. Thanks a lot! How do I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `AccToken` should be without brackets `{ }` like: `objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & AccToken`
2. You `Dim Json` but you set no value to this variable (it is empty) and so you send and empty request `objHTTP.send (Json)`.
3. Your `LongURL` shoud not go into tho `.Open` but into your `JSON` so it needs to be `objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False` and `Json = "{""long_url"": ""https://dev.bitly.com"",   ""domain"": ""bit.ly"",   ""group_guid"": ""Ba1bc23dE4F""}"`

It should look something like below:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B6:B100")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'If users selects more than one cell, exit sub to prevent bugs
    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim AccToken As String
    AccToken = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
    If AccToken = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your Bitly Access Token to get started" & vbCrLf & "hoi"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim LongURL As String
    LongURL = Target.Value
    
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten"

    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False

    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & AccToken
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
    
    Dim Json As String
    Json = "{""long_url"": """ & LongURL & """,   ""domain"": ""bit.ly"",   ""group_guid"": ""Ba1bc23dE4F""}"
    
    objHTTP.send Json
    
    Dim result As String
    result = objHTTP.responseText
    
    Me.Range("C" & Target.Row).Value = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
    
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my tutor. I have tested the code but the same error `{"message":"FORBIDDEN",`!